# What is the greatest observed distance between clearly entangled particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

As far as I can understand, decoherence will break entanglement. Given that, what is the greatest distance between entangled pairs, that has been successfully observed?

Is it possible to identify entanglement in observations of distant photons (and differentiate it, say, from any statistical coincidence)?

Answer (score 14):

A very recent [paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/112/46/14202.full?sid=21f12ac3-96f6-44ce-af71-3d6820d38913) from Anton Zeilinger's group (see also an older related one [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3909)) describes an entanglement swapping experiment with two pairs of entangled photons 143 km apart, between the islands of La Palma and Tenerife (Canary Islands). They claim an expectation value for the entanglement-witness operator that is more than 6 SDs beyond the classical limit. Remarkably, this is a free-space experiment. The authors hope to eventually demonstrate a true quantum repeater "over a realistic high-loss and even turbulent quantum channel". Here's a diagram of their setup:
[image]